# Insert trigger will not work properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I am trying to create a database trigger that will update certain characters in a field for a table when a user inserts data into the table...
Ex.

```
ID  EXCHANGE   LEADRT
1    new         L-3
2    new         3
3    new         5
```

So I would want to leave id 1 alone because the format for the LEADRT is correct but ids 2 and 3 are not.

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerupdate ON PoleUnits FOR INSERT, 
UPDATE AS 
if not exists (select * from Poleunits where LEADRT like '%L-%') 
update PoleUnits set LEADRT = STUFF (LEADRT, 1, 0,'L-');
```

Any ideas why I can't get this to work or better suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Please indicate which flavour of SQL / RDBMs this is for.

Comment: what you trie to do? Update `LEADRT` column with `L-3` and `L-5`?

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio 2012.  If the LEADRT field gets populate incorrectly with a 3 I want the trigger to update the LEADRT field and insert an 'L-' so the data would then look like L-3.

Comment: I was actually able to get the following to work on data that is input without the L-.  However, if the L- is in the LEADRT the trigger inserts a second L-.  So, the data looks like L-L-3.  Any ideas on how to stop that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In insert and update triggers you have access to a specific table called `inserted` where the rows to be inserted/updated are held. Those are not real tables, they are just logical tables with the same structure as the table on which the trigger fired.

Your current logic works on the original table, thus working with all the existing data, but not with the data you are actually inserting, i.e. it will update everything except the data you actually want updated. Something like this could work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerupdate ON PoleUnits 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS 
  update PoleUnits
  set LEADRT = STUFF (PoleUnits.LEADRT, 1, 0,'L-')
  from PoleUnits 
    inner join inserted  -- this is basically a self join
      on PoleUnits.ID = inserted.ID
  where PoleUnits.LEADRT not like '%L-%'
```

This will only update those rows in PoleUnits that are being inserted, and only if their LEADRT field is not in the L- format.

Comment: When I ran that I received the following:

Msg 286, Level 16, State 1, Procedure triggerupdate, Line 3
The logical tables INSERTED and DELETED cannot be updated.

Comment: Indeed, I just typed it in automatically :), will edit the answer

Comment: Alright, now I get this:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure triggerupdate, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: And now it had a stray `;`

Comment: Works like a charm now.  I made one edit in the set statement due to an ambiguous column name message.  Thanks for all your help.